# Not able to display grid in admin area of custom module

Tags: grid, module

I am new to magento. I am creating custom module and trying to display custom grid in admin area of custom module but I am not able to display grid. I found related questions but still not getting expected output. Not able to figure out where exactly problem. Please help me out.

`_prepareCollection()` returns `boolean false`.

please check my code below:

```
<?php

class Bespoke_Suites_Block_Adminhtml_Suites_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid{

public function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('suitesGrid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('suites_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

public function _prepareCollection(){
    $collection = Mage::getModel('bespoke_suites/suites')->getCollection();
    var_dump($collection);//returns boolean false
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();

}

protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('material', array(
           'type' => 'text',
           'index' => 'material',
           'header' => Mage::helper('suites')->__('Material')
    ));

    $this->addColumn('color', array(
           'type'=>'text',
           'index'=>'color',
           'header'=>$this->__('Color')
    ));

    $this->addColumn('measurements', array(
           'type'=> 'text',
           'index'=>'measurements',
           'header'=>$this->__('Measurements')
    ));

    $this->addColumn('thread', array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'index'=>'thread',
            'header'=>$this->__('Thread')
    ));

    $this->addColumn('buttons', array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'index'=>'buttons',
            'header'=>$this->__('Buttons')
    ));

    $this->addColumn('collar', array(
            'type'=> 'text',
            'index'=>'collar',
            'header'=>$this->__('Collar Style')
    ));

    $this->addColumn('handcuff', array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'index'=>'handcuff',
            'header'=>$this->__('Handcuff Style')
    ));

    $this->addColumn('pocket', array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'index'=>'pocket',
            'header'=>$this->__('Pocket Style')
    ));

    $this->addColumn('back', array(
            'type'=> 'text',
            'index'=>'back',
            'header'=>$this->__('Back Style')
    ));
    return $this;
}

public function getRowUrl($row){
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/view',array('id'=>$row->getId()));
}

public function getGridUrl(){
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}
}
```

And my `gridAction()` is

```
public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    /**
     * Display sample text in admin area
     *  */

    $this->_addContent(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text')->setText('Some Text')
    );

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Name Module'));
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('Suites')->__('Name - Module');
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('bespoke_suites/adminhtml_suites_grid')->toHtml()
    );

    $this->_setActiveMenu('suites');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <Bespoke_Suites>
        <version>1.0.0.0.1</version>
    </Bespoke_Suites>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <bespoke_suites>
            <class>Bespoke_Suites_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>suites_resource</resourceModel>
        </bespoke_suites>
        <!-- <suites_resource>
            <class>Bespoke_Suites_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <suites>
                    <table>bespoke_suites</table>
                </suites>
            </entities>
        </suites_resource>
        -->
        <bespoke_suites_resource>
            <class>Bespoke_Suites_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <suites>
                    <table>bespoke_suites</table>
                </suites>
            </entities>
        </bespoke_suites_resource>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <bespoke_suites>
            <class>Bespoke_Suites_Helper</class>
        </bespoke_suites>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <bespoke_suites>
            <class>Bespoke_Suites_Block</class>
        </bespoke_suites>
        <suites>
            <class>Bespoke_Suites_Block</class>
        </suites>
    </blocks>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <bespoke_suites_grid>Bespoke_Suites_Block_Adminhtml_Bespoke_Suites_Grid</bespoke_suites_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
    <resource>
        <bespoke_suites_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Bespoke_Suites</module>
                <class>Bespoke_Suites_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </bespoke_suites_setup>
        <bespoke_suites_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </bespoke_suites_write>
        <bespoke_suites_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </bespoke_suites_read>
    </resource>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <!-- <bespoke_suites>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Bespoke_Suites</module>
                <frontName>suites</frontName>
            </args>
        </bespoke_suites> -->
        <suites>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Bespoke_Suites</module>
                <frontName>suites</frontName>
            </args>
        </suites>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <suites>
                <file>suites.xml</file>
            </suites>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <!-- <layout>
        <updates>
            <bespoke_suites>
                <file>bespoke_suites.xml</file>
            </bespoke_suites>
        </updates>
    </layout> -->
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Bespoke_Suites before="Mage_Adminhtml">Bespoke_Suites_adminhtml</Bespoke_Suites>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <bespoke_suites>
                <file>suites.xml</file>
            </bespoke_suites>
            <suites>
                <file>suites.xml</file>
            </suites>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: can you add the `config.xml` file?

Comment: @Marius   updated config.xml file

Comment: @Marius, i created table manually.Table is not creating when i execute script.

Comment: can you add menu in config.xml or adminhtml.xml file?

Comment: @Abdul         ya,already there in adminhtml.xml

Comment: you are going wrong way.

Comment: @Abdul         tell me what i have to change? can i add it in config.xml?

Comment: I am giving step by steps code and please follow on this way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31298/discussion-between-nagendra-and-abdul).

Comment: @Marius @Abdul is this because of model directory name?In my `local.xml` and `config.xml`,model name is **mysql4**

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your config file.

```
<resourceModel>suites_resource</resourceModel>
```

should be

```
<resourceModel>bespoke_suites_resource</resourceModel>
```

and

```
    <bespoke_suites_resource>
        <class>Bespoke_Suites_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <suites>
                <table>bespoke_suites</table>
            </suites>
        </entities>
    </bespoke_suites_resource>
```

Should be

```
    <bespoke_suites_resource>
        <class>Bespoke_Suites_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <suites>
                <table>bespoke_suites</table>
            </suites>
        </entities>
    </bespoke_suites_resource>
```

and I'm not sure you need this:

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <bespoke_suites_grid>Bespoke_Suites_Block_Adminhtml_Bespoke_Suites_Grid</bespoke_suites_grid>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

Comment: ok,let me check

Comment: No Marius,if i change config.xml file,getting fatal error.

Comment: I have no other idea. Check the logs maybe.

Comment: @marian        Is it because i created table manually?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.